# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined?

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to send data from the inputpage "addbook.php" to the insertpage "postbook.php" that send it to my Database.

I am very newbie to PHP but on my way learning it now. So have now tried hundreds of times to get this to work, but i always encounter problems...

**PHP/ PDO** - postbook.php

```
<?php
    # pdo options/attributes
    $opt = array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    # data source name
    $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=book";
    # basic pdo connection (with added option for error handling)
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

            try {
                $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=book', 'root', '');
                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO English books VALUES :English title");
                $arrayName = array(':English title' => $_POST['Etitle']);


                $result = $stmt->execute($arrayName);

                if($result) {
                    echo "<p>Data submitted successfully!</p>";
                }

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            echo "<p>Successfully connected!</p>";
        }
   # close the connection  
    $DBH = null;

?>
```

**HTML/ input** - addbook.php

```
<form action="postbook.php" method="post" />
<p>English title: <input type="text" name="Etitle" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Comment: `:English title` is not a valid placeholder, `:English_title` is a valid one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:English title` is not a valid placeholder name. PDO/SQL cannot distinguish whether you mean one placeholder `:English` followed by the keyword `title` (which would be the usual SQL syntax, and is how it's interpreted, and is invalid syntax), or whether you mean a placeholder with a space in the middle.

You'll have to name your placeholder `:englishTitle` or something similar, **without space**. The same goes for your table name.

You're also missing parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO english_books VALUES (:englishTitle)
```

Comment: Thanks!! But it still does not store the data into the table? It only says Succesfully connected?

Comment: @Zarzarki: there was an error with your query. Do a `print_r($stmt->errorInfo())` to see what it was.

Comment: @halfer Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Array'' at line 1 ) Can you do anything about this? :P

Comment: I bet `$_POST['Etitle']` is an array and not a string, and so it gets confused. Do a `print_r($_POST['Etitle'])` and see what you get. This needs to be a string.

Comment: (It is a surprising error though, as it seems that the injected parameter is not being quoted, and thus is causing a syntax error. If my help above does not solve it, you may need to update your question (if it can be written as a minor addition) or ask a new one (if it is essentially a different question).